# How do you use a regular for-loop to determine the maximum calculated area of the square array in this situation?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming and find arrays to be quite confusing.This is what I have so far. I am hoping someone can help explain to me why I cant set maxArea to squareArray[0] and how I should go about doing so. I need to be able to return the maxArea of the squareArray as a double using a for-loop while calling the calculateArea method for each square object.

```
public class Square{

private double sideLength;

public Square (double lengthOfSides){
  sideLength = lengthOfSides;
  }

public double calculateArea (){
double Area;
Area = sideLength * sideLength;
return Area;
}


public static double findMaximumArea(Square[] squareArray){
double maxArea;
squareArray[0] = maxArea;

for(int i = 0; i < squareArray.length; i++){
if(squareArray[i] > maxArea){
 maxArea = squareArray[i];
  }
  return maxArea;
   }
  }
 }
```

And the main

```
public class SquareArrayTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Square testSquare = new Square(15);
    if (testSquare.calculateArea() == 225) {
        System.out.println(testSquare.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Your Square class is correct!");
    }

    Square square1 = new Square(23.5);
    Square square2 = new Square(33.3);
    Square square3 = new Square(14.9);
    Square square4 = new Square(11.7); 

  Square[] squareArray = new Square[4];
  squareArray[0] = square1;
  squareArray[1] = square2;
  squareArray[2] = square3;
  squareArray[3] = square4;

 }
```

}

Comment: use maxArea = squareArray[i].sideLength;

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your code line by line:

```
public static double findMaximumArea(Square[] squareArray){
```

So this method returns the area of the biggest square among all the squares of the squareArray. Fine.

```
    double maxArea;
    squareArray[0] = maxArea;
```

In these lines, your intention is to initialize the current max area with the one of the first square of the array. But the assignment is in the wrong order, and you're not actually computing the area. I read `=` as *becomes*. So the above line means:

> The first element of the array *becomes* the maxArea.

What you actually want is

> maxArea *becomes* the area of the first element of the array:

```
double maxArea = squareArray[0].calculateArea();
```

Let's continue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < squareArray.length; i++){
```

So you loop over all the quares in the array. Fine, even if you could start from the second element, since you've already computed the area of the first one.

```
if (squareArray[i] > maxArea){
    maxArea = squareArray[i];
```

This time, the assignment is in the correct order. But once again, you're comparing a square (`squareArray[i]`, of type Square) with an area (`maxArea`, of type `double`). You need to compute the area of the current element, and to compare it to the max area:

```
 double area = squareArray[i].calculateArea();
 if (area > maxArea) {
     maxArea = area;
 }
```

Let's continue:

```
    return maxArea;
}
```

That is fine.